# Can cosmos db id be override to integer type?

Tags: python, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to manually specify the **id** field of my documents, however I can not find how can I insert an integer value for the property.

I am using python module of azure.cosmos and when I try to insert an integer value, it seems to hit an error in the sdk implementation, in particular here.

```
 @staticmethod
 def __ValidateResource(resource):
    id = resource.get('id')
    if id:
        if id.find('/') != -1 or id.find('\\') != -1 or id.find('?') != -1 
             or id.find('#') != -1:
            raise ValueError('Id contains illegal chars.')

        if id[-1] == ' ':
            raise ValueError('Id ends with a space.')
```

I am guessing this field is not designed to be used as I intend and there should be no need to make in an integer, however it would be good if some light is shed on the matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cosmos DB's `id` property may only be a string. You'd need to convert your integer value into a string value to use it as `id`.

Comment: Well I did that, however I was wandering if there was a way to make it int?

Comment: Right. Just clarifying that you cannot use any data type other than string for `id`. Note: if you absolutely had to have an integer value (e.g. for specific range queries), then you'd need to have a different property to store the integer representation of the id.

Comment: @DavidMakogon could you provide link from documentation which says that id has to be a string?

Comment: @fascynacja - You can look at the Cosmos DB REST API documentation. The page for Documents explicitly states that the `id` property is a string, up to 255 characters.You can also see it yourself via quick demo: go to the portal, create a new container (even specifying a different property as partition key, making no assumption about `id`), and try creating a document with a non-string `id`, which will return an error explicitly telling you that it must be a string.

Comment: David I have made the test already:) Just wanted to see it written my Microsoft, also with explanation why it has to be string. I found the link you mentioned: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/documents